# Showing Calendar Using JavaScript Function

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, visual-studio-2010, calendar

I want to make a calendar that display itself on clicking to the calendar image, and whenever a date is selected, it is shown in the textbox. I have done this part but the problem is whenever I change the month of the calendar, the page refreshes itself and the calendar display becomes none again while on clicking the calendar image again, the calendar displays the next month. I want to change the month of the calendar without making the page refresh.

I am making it in Visual Studio. I search for the query on the site but almost all answers uses PHP(which I don't understand).

Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <img alt="" src="CalendarImage.jpg" width="20px" height="20px" onclick="show()" /> </br>
<div id="cal">
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
</div>
```

OnChangingSelectedDate

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCal.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
```

StyleSheet:

```
#cal
        {
            display: none; 
        }
```

JavaScript Function:

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: why not use jquery calendar(http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: also do you get any errors?

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors but the page refresh itself and thus making the display of the calendar to none everytime I change month. And I don't know JQuery, I want to make it using JavaScript only.

Comment: It will do postback always as you have onselectionchanged event..any reason for using javascript? as jquery would be just one or two line to make it work and really easy...

Comment: Yes, I get to know that JQuery is better to use (by the link you provided). Thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

use this java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
   function popupCalendar()
    {
      var dateField = document.getElementById('dateField'); // toggle the div 
      if (dateField.style.display == 'none') 
        dateField.style.display = 'block'; 
      else dateField.style.display = 'none';          

     } 
 </script>
```

and a textbox:

```
      <asp:TextBox id="txtDate" Runat="server" /> <img src="cal.png"    onclick="popupCalendar()" />
```

and a calendar in div tag:

```
    <div id="dateField" style="display:none;">  
<asp:Calendar id="calDate" OnSelectionChanged="calDate_SelectionChanged"  
        Runat="server" SelectionMode="Day" 
        onvisiblemonthchanged="calDate_VisibleMonthChanged" /> </div>
```

and in the code behind:

```
     protected void calDate_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDate.Text = calDate.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
}
 protected void calDate_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "<script language=JavaScript>popupCalendar();</script>");
}
```